# User deleted own answered post

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5473576/ahsen-rauf/) asked a question which I then answered. He accepted my answer. He then asked another question. One day I found that both questions had been deleted, presumably by himself. The user himself is not deleted. I cannot tell him to undelete the questions because he has no posts on the site. How can I inform him that you should not delete questions just because they have been answered? Is there anything else I should do instead?

Comment: Indeed. Both posts were self-deleted. I don't see why OP would do that.

Comment: [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316330/how-to-blit-a-random-image-from-a-list-pygame) and [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270367/how-to-show-many-different-images-pygame).

Comment: Deleting your question after it's been answered is bad form. I voted to undelete both questions.

Comment: Both questions were downvoted, tends to inspire the OP to delete his question.  There isn't much to stop him from doing so when it doesn't have an upvoted answer.  You can certainly flag a moderator and ask him to undelete it again.  Just make sure you actually want to support the answer for the rest of your natural life.

Comment: That question doesn't seem worth answering to me - it stems from the OP's inability to break down their problem into component parts, which is a tougher thing to teach and not suited to SO. The user learns nothing useful from the answer but gets some trivial copy+paste code (and their continued lack of understanding is demonstrated by their later comments). I'd say it should have been closed and eventually cleaned up by the cleanup script (as it was, it would eventually have been caught by the cleanup script anyway, but now your answer has upvotes so it won't). See: "help vampire".

Comment: Both questions are now undeleted.

Comment: That post rang a bell for me - and indeed, this is one of those "This is not the same as any others because it does not focus on pictures exactly". Happy to see it pop up again - anyone care to close it now as a clear duplicate?

Comment: @Jongware I'd gladly help you close it, but the question you referenced is only asking how to get a random element, rather than how to get a series of random elements without repetition ("then make sure i dont open that image up again"). So while the OP's complaint that it doesn't use pictures is crazy, I'd say it actually isn't a suitable duplicate here (though it could be argued that the asker could break down their issue further until it is helpful).

Comment: @Dave: the accepted answer does not, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16514203/2564301) does. There may be a more exact duplicate though.